# Infor Application Studio: current year

Tags: combobox

I'm new in Infor Application Studio... 
I have a combobox with periods (months/years from 2010). 
What I want is to show always the current year, how can I do?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Not a lot...in a cell the formula =TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()); "0000")... than I created a new global variable to use in a combobox (in and out) but I don't know how to assign the value of the formula above to the global variable... in order to select the value of the global variable in the combobox... (sorry for my English... I'm Italian!)

Comment: Is this part of LN?